# Spark performance - how to parallelize large loops?

Tags: performance, scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark

I have a Spark application containing 8000 loops totally and it runs on a cluster of 5 nodes. Each node has 125GB memory and 32 cores. The code in concern looks like the following:

```
for (m <- 0 until deviceArray.size) { // there are 1000 device 
  var id = deviceArray(m)

  for (t <- 1 to timePatterns) { // there are 8 time patterns
     var hrpvData = get24HoursPVF(dataDF, id, t).cache()

  var hrpvDataZI = hrpvData.zipWithIndex

  var clustersLSD = runKMeans(hrpvData, numClusters, numIterations)

  var clusterPVPred = hrpvData.map(x => clustersLSD.predict(x))
  var clusterPVMap = hrpvDataZI.zip(clusterPVPred)

  var pvhgmRDD = clusterPVMap.map{r => (r._2, r._1._2)}.groupByKey

  var arrHGinfo = pvhgmRDD.collect 

  // Post process data 
  // .....

  hrpvData.unpersist()
  }
}
```

The function call `get24HoursPVF()` prepares feature vectors for k-means, and it takes about 40 seconds.    Each loop takes about 50 seconds to finish using the cluster. My data size is from 2 to 3 GB (read from tables). Given 8000 loops, the total time running this Spark application is unacceptable (8000x50s).

Since each device is independent, is there any way to parallelize the 8000 iterations? Or how to utilize clusters to solve the problem of total long running time? Scala Future won't work because it just submits jobs near simultaneously but Spark won't run these jobs simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the for loops, you've got 2 of the slowest API calls in Spark in your code there - `groupByKey`, and `collect`.

groupByKey should almost never be used, instead look at `reduceByKey`, see this [Databricks blog](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) for more details.

`collect` transfers all the data in that RDD to an array on the driver node, unless that's a small amount of data it'll have a fairly big performance impact.

On the for loops, I'm not particularly familiar with what you're trying to do, but in

```
var hrpvData = get24HoursPVF(dataDF, id, t).cache()
```

you're building and caching a new dataframe for each id and t value. I'm not sure why you couldn't just build one single dataframe containing each variant of id and t at the start, then run your zipWithIndex, map, etc over that whole dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree that groupByKey should be replaced by reduceByKey, but in this context the time on groupByKey can be ignored compared with other time-consuming parts. Collect() transfers small amount of data here.  I need to run k-means clustering on each device with each time pattern, which is the reason I think I have to build and cache a new dataframe for each id and t (and thus for a feature vector).

Comment: Your comment makes me thinking again why I can't build one single big dataframe. Actually I can. At least in this way I am able to move the function call get24HoursPVF() outside the 8000 loops, although I still need to run k-means clustering 8000 times. So it will cut running time. Thanks again!

Comment: To be precise `groupByKey` isn't more expensive than any operation that requires shuffling a similar amount of data. It means that following this logic you should avoid `join`, `coogroup`, `partitionBy` or any similar method.

Comment: Except for the big difference that join, cogroup, etc, don't have an easy no-shuffle alternative

Comment: If you need group and not group followed by some-reduction then groupBy key has no alternative either. It is more _Don't use groupByKey if you mean reduceByKey_ than _Avoid GroupByKey_. And groupByKey doesn't have no-shuffle alternative - it has only -ess-to-shuffle alternatives.

Comment: @zero323 Does it mean it will also hamper the performance if we use the  this query using the CassandraSQLContext `Select Column1, max(Column2) from Table_name Group by Column1`. If, yes what is the alternative for the to convert it to `reduceby`